# Apple Sign-in not working on iOS 14 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios14, apple-sign-in

When I try to log in for the simulator in iOS 14, the loading spinner just spins forever. There is a thread for this on the Apple developer forums [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533) but no solutions and no response from Apple. I can certainly test on the device, but testing on the simulator is obviously easier for iteration. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 38):

***2nd Updates***

The problem seems to still exist in iOS 15 and iOS15.1.

***Updates***

The problem has not been fixed in iOS 14.4 nor iOS 14.5.

***Original***

This is one of the known issues in iOS 14, that has not been solved by Apple as of today yet. (almost 4 months old) The problem has not been fixed in iOS 14.0 launch, iOS 14.1 launch or iOS 14.2 launch. *Not in 14.3 launch* as well.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533

A workaround is to use iOS 13.x simulator until that issue is fixed (feel free to chime in or call support line to increase the thread's visibility). Unfortunately, the workaround won't work if you use iOS 14 features in your app, as it won't run in iOS 13.x simulators.

Comment: I download ios13.5 and signin into the simulator through setting is crashing the simulator. I'm now downloading 13.7.

Comment: even on iOS 15 simulators the issue still exists

Comment: Doesn't work on 15.1 as well. I hope Apple didn't forget about this bug!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Tried it on 13.2 and it worked!

Comment: Still happening on iOS 15.2. Unbelievable

Comment: still happening on iOS 15.3.X

Comment: Still happening on iOS 15.4

Comment: Still there in 15.5

Comment: It works fine on iOS 13.7 simulator

Comment: Still isn't working on iOS 15.5 simulator.

Comment: Still not working on iOS 15.2 using Xcode 13.2.1 - just an eternal spinner after entering the password. I downloaded iOS 13.5, and in that simulator it worked.

Comment: Its working fine on iOS 16.2

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Xcode 13.4, iOS 15.4 and the problem still exists.  2FA is not triggered from the Simulator.

Using an iOS 13.x Simulator and password login will work, but it is clunky.  You'll need to add your user to the Settings Apple ID panel and make sure that 2FA is triggered when logging in.  It took two tries for me to get it to succeed and make it past the password screen.

On Simulators of 14.0 and 15.4, when using the password screen with the blue Continue button, the spinning wait cursor will never time out and 2FA will never be triggered.