# IOS Simulator Unable to Sign In with Apple ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have XCode 12.5 and iPhone simulator with IOS 14.5.
when I do Sign in with Apple ID and enter my email and password and click the "Continue" button the spinner just keeps spinning.
This is a Known bug in IOS/Simulator, not related to my app code.
Does anyone know how to fix it?
I'm attaching a screenshot.[image: Apple ID Login]

Comment: Seems you are not the first: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally works on the iOS 16 simulator and XCode 14 Beta 3.

Comment: Yes, it is confirmed, it works with XCode 14 Beta 3

Comment: Finally after so many years.  Thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I logedin in iCloud https://www.icloud.com/ and accepted the terms and conditions after login I could connect my AppleID in the simulator.

Cheers.

Comment: not working, same wheel spinning on password validation.

Comment: still facing this issue

Comment: worked like a magic, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

crazy that in dec 2022, with Xcode 14.1 and simulator iOS 16, this is still an issue.  I found that if I sign in to an iCloud account, then sign out, then sign in again, it works.  It still doesn't present 2-factor auth, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with iOS 14+ simulators try with iOS 13.7 it works fine for me.
[Apple Sign-in not working on iOS 14 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392755/apple-sign-in-not-working-on-ios-14-simulator)